# If-Else statement not working in Android app

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext, spinner

I have a simple **if-else** statement in my app, but it's not working. If I choose "**day**" in my **Spinner**, only that day can be edited. It's not working because all days can still be edited. Can someone tell me why?

```
final String[] items={"Day","Date","Time","Location"};

    mSpin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(
        new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(
                AdapterView<?> parent2, View view, int pos, long id
            ) {
String strsel=items[pos];
if(strsel.equalsIgnoreCase("Day")) {
    btnChangeDate.setFocusable(false);
    btnChangeDate.setEnabled(false);
    //btnChangeDate.setClickable(false);
    btnChangeTime.setFocusable(false);
    btnChangeTime.setEnabled(false);
    //btnChangeTime.setClickable(false);
    mLatitude.setFocusable(false);
    mLatitude.setEnabled(false);
    mLongitude.setFocusable(false);
    mLongitude.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    mMonday.setFocusable(true);
    mMonday.setEnabled(true);
    mTuesday.setFocusable(true);
    mTuesday.setEnabled(true);
    mWednesday.setFocusable(true);
    mWednesday.setEnabled(true);
    mThursday.setFocusable(true);
    mThursday.setEnabled(true);
    mFriday.setFocusable(true);
    mFriday.setEnabled(true);
    mSaturday.setFocusable(true);
    mSaturday.setEnabled(true);
    mSunday.setFocusable(true);
    mSunday.setEnabled(true);
} 

String strsel2=items[pos];
if(strsel2.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
    mMonday.setFocusable(false);
    mMonday.setEnabled(false);
    mTuesday.setFocusable(false);
    mTuesday.setEnabled(false);
    mWednesday.setFocusable(false);
    mWednesday.setEnabled(false);
    mThursday.setFocusable(false);
    mThursday.setEnabled(false);
    mFriday.setFocusable(false);
    mFriday.setEnabled(false);
    mSaturday.setFocusable(false);
    mSaturday.setEnabled(false);
    mSunday.setFocusable(false);
    mSunday.setEnabled(false);
    btnChangeTime.setFocusable(false);
    btnChangeTime.setEnabled(false);
    //btnChangeTime.setClickable(false);
    mLatitude.setFocusable(false);
    mLatitude.setEnabled(false);
    mLongitude.setFocusable(false);
    mLongitude.setEnabled(false);                           
} else {
    btnChangeDate.setFocusable(true);
    btnChangeDate.setEnabled(true);
}

String strsel3=items[pos];
if(strsel3.equalsIgnoreCase("Time")) {
    mMonday.setFocusable(false);
    mMonday.setEnabled(false);
    mTuesday.setFocusable(false);
    mTuesday.setEnabled(false);
    mWednesday.setFocusable(false);
    mWednesday.setEnabled(false);
    mThursday.setFocusable(false);
    mThursday.setEnabled(false);
    mFriday.setFocusable(false);
    mFriday.setEnabled(false);
    mSaturday.setFocusable(false);
    mSaturday.setEnabled(false);
    mSunday.setFocusable(false);
    mSunday.setEnabled(false);
    btnChangeDate.setFocusable(false);
    btnChangeDate.setEnabled(false);
    //btnChangeDate.setClickable(false);
    mLatitude.setFocusable(false);
    mLatitude.setEnabled(false);
    mLongitude.setFocusable(false);
    mLongitude.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    btnChangeTime.setFocusable(true);
    btnChangeTime.setEnabled(true);
}

String strsel4=items[pos];
if(strsel.equalsIgnoreCase("Location")) {
    mMonday.setFocusable(false);
    mMonday.setEnabled(false);
    mTuesday.setFocusable(false);
    mTuesday.setEnabled(false);
    mWednesday.setFocusable(false);
    mWednesday.setEnabled(false);
    mThursday.setFocusable(false);
    mThursday.setEnabled(false);
    mFriday.setFocusable(false);
    mFriday.setEnabled(false);
    mSaturday.setFocusable(false);
    mSaturday.setEnabled(false);
    mSunday.setFocusable(false);
    mSunday.setEnabled(false);
    btnChangeDate.setFocusable(false);
    btnChangeDate.setEnabled(false);
    //btnChangeDate.setClickable(false);
btnChangeTime.setFocusable(false);
btnChangeTime.setEnabled(false);
//btnChangeTime.setClickable(false);
} else {
    //mLatitude.setFocusable(true);
    mLatitude.setEnabled(true);
    //mLongitude.setFocusable(true);
    mLongitude.setEnabled(true);
} 
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you show us how `items` and `pos` are calculated?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the "if" statements and see (a) if they're even executed, and (b) if they contain the value you think they do.

Comment: Here's my recommendation in order to receive helpful responses from the community: it is great to post source code, but only the source code that is relavent to the question. In your case, you posted many redundant lines of code within each `if` clause; the code within the braces are not imperative to the content of the question. Next time, I suggest you replace these many lines of code inside the `if` statements with a one-liner like `// some code here`.

Comment: Does it go inside if statement?

Comment: thank you for all of your comments... @323go i will try implement the breakpoint..

Comment: You can try switch using the pos value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've looked over your code again. You're either doing something that is not obvious, or you're not using the `else` case as it ought to be used. One way or the other, you do know that the results you're getting are wrong. I would suggest rewrite the listener after the pattern below. You may have to fine-tune it based on your actual requirements:

```
static final int dayIndex  = 0;
static final int dateIndex = 1;
static final int timeIndex = 2;
static final int locIndex  = 3;

public void onItemSelected( AdapterView<?> parent2, View view, int pos, long id ) {
    mMonday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mMonday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );
    mTuesday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mTuesday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );
    mWednesday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mWednesday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );
    mThursday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mThursday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );
    mFriday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mFriday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );
    mSaturday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mSaturday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );
    mSunday.setFocusable( pos == dayIndex );
    mSunday.setEnabled( pos == dayIndex );

    btnChangeDate.setFocusable( pos == dateIndex );
    btnChangeDate.setEnabled( pos == dateIndex );

    btnChangeTime.setFocusable( pos == timeIndex );
    btnChangeTime.setEnabled( pos == timeIndex );

    mLatitude.setEnabled( pos == locIndex );
    mLongitude.setEnabled( pos == locIndex );
}
```

The code above will enable mMonday..mSunday if you select the first item (Day) in the spinner, otherwise disable them. It'll enable btnChangeDate if you select the second item (Date)... etc. Note that if I guessed your intention correctly, and this code works, then your understanding of the if/then/else construct is quite flawed and you might want to read up on that.

Comment: can i ask you something via your emel perhaps??

Comment: You can ask here. I only have enough time to do email support for clients.

Comment: okey, tq. i have another problem. and i hope that you can help me. i want to display the data from SQLite database in textview based on the type of trigger like the above (day, date, time n location). i follow the tutorial from http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2011/02/listview-of-data-from-sqlitedatabase.html but the data do not appear at all. is thre somthing wrong with it?

Comment: Hard to tell without code. Why don't you start a new question and include your code.

Comment: This is a new question. Please follow S.O. guidelines.